# Nested loop JSON array ionic 3

Tags: arrays, json, ionic-framework, ionic3, ionic-view

I have an issue to display data, currently my view is like this[image: view] .

and my database in table 'jadual' is like this [image: database] The orange box is a name from pelajar_id column, and the time at below is timestamp from jadual_scan column. and my expected view is like this.

```
-------------------------------
Wafi Dania                     |
-------------------------------
scan       |   08:12:13        |
           |   03:35:28        |
--------------------------------

--------------------------------
Assi                            |
--------------------------------
Scan       |   11:24:18         |
--------------------------------
```

you can refer my source code in .html

```
<ion-label>
        Date: {{myDate}}
    </ion-label>
  <ion-list *ngFor="let item of data">
      <ion-item color="primary">
          <ion-label><h2>{{item.pelajar_nama}}</h2></ion-label>
      </ion-item>
      <ion-grid>
          <ion-row color=primary>
            <ion-col>
              Scan
            </ion-col>
              <ion-col>
               {{ item.jadual_scan  | date: 'hh:mm:ss' }}
              </ion-col>
            </ion-row>
        </ion-grid>
  </ion-list>
```

and my  .ts file

```
getAttendance(){
        this.restProvider.getAttendance().then(data=>{
        this.data=data;
       // for(let i=0; i<this.data.length; ++i){
          //this.myArray.push({'displayName': this.data[i].pelajar_nama});
         // for(let j=0; j<this.myArray[i].length; ++j){
          //  this.inside.push({"displayInside": this.myArray[j].jadual_scan})
          //}
          //for (let j=0; j<this.data[i].pelajar_nama[j].length; ++j){
           //this.myArray[i].inside[j].push({'displayName':this.data[i].pelajar_nama[j].jadual_scan});
          //}
       // }
                console.log(this.data);
            });
  }
```

this is get data from API

```
$parentId  = \Auth::guard('api')->user()->id;
        $student = DB::table('pelajar')
                ->join ('jadual','jadual.pelajar_id','pelajar.pelajar_id')
                ->select('pelajar.*','jadual.*')
                ->whereDate('jadual.jadual_scan', DB::raw('CURDATE()'))
                ->where('pelajar.penjaga_id',$parentId)
                ->orderBy('pelajar.pelajar_id','asc')
                ->get();
        return $student;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<ion-list *ngFor="let item of data"> 
  <ion-item color="primary">
   <ion-label> 
 <h2>{{item.pelajar_nama}}</h2> 
 </ion-label>  
</ion-item> 
<ion-grid>
<ion-row color=primary>
  <ion-col>
    Scan
  </ion-col>
  <ion-col *ngFor="let date of item.dates">
    {{ date.jadual_scan | date: 'hh:mm:ss' }}
  </ion-col>
</ion-row>
```

u forgot to iterate loop for date display

Comment: thank you for the answer,  but my view looks like same  as above and my date.jadual_scan is not showing. what's does means for item.dates ? do i have create a new array?/

Comment: no, it's just a .html , sorry if i misunderstand your question

Comment: I just updated  my  question with get  data from API, please note that database picture as above is table 'jadual'

Comment: the data i only have at the pictures above,  'jadual' table, in second image